# Form Submit to URL based on Value

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

This may sound weird but i trying to make a form that submit to different page according to the value of database

Database

```
| value | etc.Info 
    1
  -----
```

Code

```
<form action="?I donno put what to determind them to go?" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Edit"/>
</form>
```

And my wish is to click the button and go to another page with name upload.php when the value is 1 on database and go to detail.php when the value is 0, any advice will be good and i thank you in advance who all wish to help

Comment: Just do a database lookup to assign the value to a variable (so ultimately, `$variable = 1`), then `echo` out that variable in the `action` (like you have done for the `input value`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the ID when the page loads you can do

```
if($_POST['id'] == 0) {
    $location = "detail.php";
} else {
    $location = "upload.php";
}
```

You can also do this is a switch statement if there are more than two options.

then your form would be

```
<form action="<?php echo $location; ?>" method="POST">
```

Comment: oh TQ this is what i searching for,even though a bit of stupid quetion

Comment: No problem, make sure to keep in consideration if for any reason the ID is not set, or does not equal 1 or 2 because right now it will always go to upload.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="anotherpage.php" method="POST">
```

In anotherpage.php

```
$yourhiddenvalue= $_POST['id'];
if($yourhiddenvalue ==0){
//redirect to detail.php
}
if($yourhiddenvalue ==1){
//redirect to upload.php
}
```

Comment: hmm since good but have to make a new page, but appreciate on what your are on

Comment: hmm maybe i self post!? quite an idea @@